# discord.py not executing math/python code

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this math code that doubles as a python command, and I want it to solve math. When I say `p!math 3+13`, it should send 16 but it's sending the problem (3+13) back at the user. Can someone help?

````py
@client.command()
async def math(ctx, *, p):
    try:
        exec(p)
        await ctx.send(p)
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"```python\nError: {e}```")
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the incorrect function. Instead of using exec, use eval.
Additionally, you should set the returned value to a parameter and return that.

For example:

````
@client.command()
async def math(ctx, *, p):
    try:
        answer = eval(p)
        await ctx.send(answer)
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"```python\nError: {e}```")
````

Answer (score 1):

Use eval instead of exec.

```
# Returns 16
try:
    res = eval('3+13')
    print(res)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# Returns None
try:
    res = exec('3+13')
    print(res)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```